# Change orientation of RTF output using R package Huxtable

Tags: r, reporting, rtf

Huxtable is one of the few package that supports writing formatted tables out to RTF, which is a necessity for what I'm trying to do (trust me, if I could avoid RTF, I would). But I haven't been able to find any options in the within the output functions for `to_rtf` or within any of the vignettes.

Ideally there would be a simple way to do this, like an option on `quick_rtf` to do something like:

```
ht <- as_hux(mtcars, add_colnames = TRUE)
bottom_border(ht)[1, ] <- 1
bold(ht)[1, ] <- TRUE
caption(ht) <- 'Cars'
width(ht) <- 1
quick_rtf(ht, file='test.rtf', orientation='landscape)
```

And I can force all cells to rotate 90 degrees, but that's not quite what I'm looking for. Does anyone have a method for doing this? Or am I overlooking something in the documentation?

I was considering post processing the text from `to_rtf`. I've referenced the RTF specification [here](http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm), and I can see the formatting options for how to set the orientation, but I'm not quite following how to apply it to the document. Any ideas?

Comment: If you want to change the orientation of the whole page, that's definitely beyond the remit of huxtable (author posting) – so yes, you will have to work out how to spit out the relevant RTF yourself....

Comment: Thank's for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've since figured out the solution to this. As @dash2 points out above, this is not a capability that's build into huxtable itself - but with some minor modifications, it's achievable.

One way is to tweak Huxtables built in `quick_rtf` function (located in R/quick-functions.R in the package). This function additionally writes the code surrounding the RTF table, including the font and color tables. It's right after those tables that you can insert some RTF code to control some document properties.

The actual keyword (referencing the [RTF specification](http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm)) that you'd want to use for landscape orientation is \lndscpsxn.

- \marglN is left margin (where N is twips - 1440 twips = 1 inch)
- \margr is right
- \margt is top
- \margb is bottom
- \paperw is the width
- \paperh is the height
- \headery is the header height
- \footery is the footer height

So if you put these all together (with a few other things), if you wanted a document with 1" margins, .5" in header and footer, 8.5" X 11" document in landscape, you'd need a string after the font and color tables that looks like this:

```
\paperw15840\paperh12240\widowctrl\ftnbj\fet0\sectd\linex0\lndscpsxn
\margl1440\margr1440\margt1440\margb1440
\headery720\footery720
```

This string comes after the font and color table, but before body of the table code starts. So in `quick_rtf` you could add an option for orientation. If the option is set to landscape, you store the above string (you can eliminate the margin and footer information to keep it simple, but those are other properties you may want to control), and add that to the section writing out the file:

```
  landscape_str <- "\\paperw15840\\paperh12240\\widowctrl\\ftnbj\\fet0\\sectd\\lndscpsxn\\linex0"

  sink(file)
  tryCatch({
    cat("{\\rtf1\\ansi\\deff0\n")
    print(fc_tbls)
    # Write landscape orientation string if selected
    if (orientation == "landscape") cat(landscape_str)
    cat("\n\n\n")
    lapply(hts, print_rtf)
    cat("\n\n\n}")
  },
    error = identity,
    finally = {sink()}
  )
```

***EDIT (28MAY2020): My team has put together the package [pharmaRTF](https://github.com/atorus-research/pharmaRTF) that adds RTF document property formatting options over `huxtable` outputs - including inserting titles/footnotes into the header and footer of the document respectively.***